# How do I insert href link in php code?

Tags: php, href

I am trying to insert a clickable link into a PHP code with no success. I only know html so I tried to insert html href code but it's not working.

Original Code:

```
echo '<br/>'.__("Your auction isn't live yet, the admin needs to approve it.</br>For more info CLICK HERE.", "AuctionTheme");
```

Now this is what I tried:

```
echo '<br/>'.__("Your auction isn't live yet, the admin needs to approve it.</br>For more info <a target="_blank" href="www.website.com">CLICK HERE</a>.", "AuctionTheme");
```

and it doesn't work instead it breaks the code.

Can anyone help me with the right code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: swap the double-quotes within the tag to single-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<br/>'."Your auction isn't live yet, the admin needs to approve it.</br>For more info <a href=\"www.website.com\" target=\"_blank\" >CLICK HERE</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic errors in your code.  Number one, you need to use proper wrapping quotes.  If you have double quotes after `echo`, you will need to escape double quotes for your href inside the anchor tag:

`echo "<a href=\"www.website.com\">Link Here</a>`

However, to avoid having to escape out your double quotes, you can wrap the echo with single quotes `'`, and use standard double quotes:

```
echo '<a href="www.website.com">Link Here</a>';
```

So, for the ease of use, your answer should be as follows:

```
<?php
    echo '<br/>Your auction isn't live yet, the admin needs to approve it.</br>For more info <a href="www.website.com" target="_blank" >CLICK HERE</a>';
?>
```

Comment: You should not just paste code, but add some explanations for others to understand it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19331347)

Comment: @AndrewShmig - Tell me, what link do you see in my answer?

Comment: your code needs an explanation. No link = just code :)

Comment: @AndrewShmig - Then fix your comment.  You're saying "while this link may answer the question..." and "Link-only answers can become invalid"...  There are no links, there for, no need for that comment.

Comment: @AndrewShmig - Updated to give better explanation.